# Click twice bug when signing out of Firebase AuthUI

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Click twice bug when signing out of Firebase AuthUI:

When I click "Sign out", it toasts "You're signed in."

When I click "Sign out" for the second time, it returns to SignInActivity.

MainActivity.java

```
case R.id.menu_sign_out:
     AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(MainActivity.this);
     startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
```

SignInActiviy.java

```
mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth)
            {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                Log.d(TAG, "[SignInActivity]current user:" + user);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    //user is signed in
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "You're signed in.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        };

@Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAuthStateListener != null)
        {
            mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

problem solve by using ".addOnCompleteListener"

it seems like that the Firebase AuthUI is Asynchronous

so after signing out call the Sign in immediately

the sign out process didn't finish yet.

```
AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
  {
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
    {
      StartActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
    }
  });
```